# Abnormal line diff appearing in sourcetree

Tags: git, diff, atlassian-sourcetree

I see certain file changes appearing in sourcetree, even though the changed content is exactly the same.
[Image taken from sourcetree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNOGK.png)

The internal diff tool used in SourceTree is the default one.
If it helps, I am using ReSharper that might be editing some of the endlines.

Comment: The line endings are different.

Comment: How do check the raw ascii representations?

Comment: I use `Notepad++` with `Show All Characters` on. The ending is `LF` or `CRLF`. Other editors should have this feature to see the endings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do check the raw ascii representations?

Try:

```
 git diff --word-diff-regex=.
```

You will see of the eol changes (end of line character)

Try to clone again your repo after

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

The [OP Shivku](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1334983/shivku) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49165903/abnormal-line-diff-appearing-in-sourcetree/49166117#comment85429297_49166117):

> This helped me confirm that the file format was originally in UTF-8 BOM format, whilst ReSharper supposedly converts the file format into UTF-8 which removes the sequence of bytes EF BB BF from the file.

See "[What's different between UTF-8 and UTF-8 without BOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2223882/6309)".

Comment: Thank you. This helped me confirm that the file format was originally in UTF-8 BOM format, whilst ReSharper supposedly converts the fiel format into UTF-8 which removes the sequence of bytes EF BB BF from the file. For further reading check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom

Comment: @Shivku Well spotted! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.